Getting an error for lightning-input-address component while saving the record
I have an LWC component that has lightning-input-address with show-address-lookup, I have kept all the fields read-only except the address search. When I search address and press the save button then get an error bad value picklist for country/territory. I have selected the United States and it shows bad value. Can anyone tell me what actually it has to be passed? I know it wants value like Ind, US but how I can pass this?
You can review below component:
HTML:
 <lightning-input-address if:true={showShippingAdd} required class="slds-size_6-of-12" style="margin-left: 5%;"
      address-label="Address Test"
      read-only
      street-label="Street Test "
      city-label="City Test"
      country-label="Country Test"
      province-label="Province Test"
      postal-code-label="PostalCode Test" 
      street={shipToStreet}
      city={shipToCity}
      province={shipToState}
      postal-code={shipToPostalCode}
      country={shipToCountry}     
      onchange={handleShippingAddChg} 
      show-address-lookup ></lightning-input-address> 

Js:
handleShippingAddChg(event) {
    console.log("event.detail--- >> ", event.detail);
    console.log("event.target--- >> ", event.target);
    console.log("street >> ", event.detail.street);
    console.log("city >> ", event.detail.city);
    console.log("state >> ", event.detail.province);
    console.log("postalcode >> ", event.detail.postalCode);
    console.log("country >> ", event.detail.country);
    console.log("country2 >> ", event.target.country);
    this.shipToStreet = event.detail.street;
    this.shipToCity = event.detail.city;
    this.shipToState = event.detail.province;
    this.shipToCountry = event.detail.country;

here country >> is coming as United States but i want to pass the value


The lightning-input-address component expects the country value in a specific format (like "US" for the United States) rather than the full country name. You can handle this by mapping the full country name to its corresponding country code.
Create a Country Code Mapping:
const countryCodeMapping = {
'United States': 'US',
'India': 'IN',
// Add other countries as needed
};


Update the handleShippingAddChg Method:
handleShippingAddChg(event) {
        console.log("event.detail--- >> ", event.detail);
        console.log("event.target--- >> ", event.target);
        console.log("street >> ", event.detail.street);
        console.log("city >> ", event.detail.city);
        console.log("state >> ", event.detail.province);
        console.log("postalcode >> ", event.detail.postalCode);
        console.log("country >> ", event.detail.country);
        console.log("country2 >> ", event.target.country);

        this.shipToStreet = event.detail.street;
        this.shipToCity = event.detail.city;
        this.shipToState = event.detail.province;
        this.shipToPostalCode = event.detail.postalCode;
        this.shipToCountry = countryCodeMapping[event.detail.country] || event.detail.country;
}       

Full Example:
HTML:
<template>
        <lightning-input-address if:true={showShippingAdd} required class="slds-size_6-of-12" style="margin-left: 5%;"
                address-label="Address Test"
                read-only
                street-label="Street Test"
                city-label="City Test"
                country-label="Country Test"
                province-label="Province Test"
                postal-code-label="PostalCode Test"
                street={shipToStreet}
                city={shipToCity}
                province={shipToState}
                postal-code={shipToPostalCode}
                country={shipToCountry}
                onchange={handleShippingAddChg}
                show-address-lookup>
        </lightning-input-address>
</template>

JS:
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

const countryCodeMapping = {
        'United States': 'US',
        'India': 'IN',
        // Add other countries as needed
};

export default class AddressComponent extends LightningElement {
        @track shipToStreet;
        @track shipToCity;
        @track shipToState;
        @track shipToPostalCode;
        @track shipToCountry;

        handleShippingAddChg(event) {
                console.log("event.detail--- >> ", event.detail);
                console.log("event.target--- >> ", event.target);
                console.log("street >> ", event.detail.street);
                console.log("city >> ", event.detail.city);
                console.log("state >> ", event.detail.province);
                console.log("postalcode >> ", event.detail.postalCode);
                console.log("country >> ", event.detail.country);
                console.log("country2 >> ", event.target.country);

                this.shipToStreet = event.detail.street;
                this.shipToCity = event.detail.city;
                this.shipToState = event.detail.province;
                this.shipToPostalCode = event.detail.postalCode;
                this.shipToCountry = countryCodeMapping[event.detail.country] || event.detail.country;
        }
}


Still getting an error,  after console 'this.shipToCountry>>  United States' is coming

@NileshWarade, Can you please provide the full code of your lwc?

above code is the code on which I am working. I mean whole code

I have tried this code in my org and it is working fine. no error throw. See this: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/49948877?key=c76ad69a5f3e4c65a65b5a8541078713

const countryCodeMapping = {   'United States': 'US',   'India': 'IN', }; by doing this change I am able to save the record. Thank you @Tushar Jadhav
